# How to call a com method with out paramter by Jacob?

Tags: java, com, jacob

I want to use Jacob for doing task with COM. But I can't find any way to invoke a method which has a out parameter, Can you provide me this sample code. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147193/cant-co-create-object-cant-find-moniker-jacob/18533406#18533406