# Can't co-create object / Can't find moniker | Jacob

Tags: java, com, jacob

When creating an `ActiveXComponent` using JACOB I get the following error.

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:99)
    at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.<init>(ActiveXComponent.java:58)
    at com.paston.jacobtest.RidderIQ.main(RidderIQ.java:30)
```

The COM object which I need to use from a program which doesn't register its DLLs by itself during installation.

To register the DLL I used the 64bit version of RegAsm according to [this](http://netheadaches.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/jacob-cant-co-create-object/) article that could help. Also, I tried to load every DLL in of the external program because I suspected that there could be "something" wrong with loading the dependencies.

Here is my current code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String dllDir = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Ridder iQ Client\\Bin\\";
    File folder = new File( dllDir );

    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        String str = fileEntry.getName();
        if (str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).equals("dll")) {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
            System.load(dllDir + str);
        }
    }

    try {
        ActiveXComponent example = new ActiveXComponent("RidderIQSDK");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When changing the name to the clsid I get a different exception.

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't find moniker
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:99)
at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.<init>(ActiveXComponent.java:58)
at com.paston.jacobtest.RidderIQ.main(RidderIQ.java:28)
```

I got JACOB to work with my code in another test using the system's Random object.

```
    ActiveXComponent random = new ActiveXComponent("clsid:4E77EC8F-51D8-386C-85FE-7DC931B7A8E7");
    Object obj = random.getObject();

    Object result = Dispatch.call((Dispatch) obj, "Next");
    System.out.println("Result: "+result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all solution and finally succeeded to crack the code related to JACOB. Create your code as per below sample code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String libFile = System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("amd64") ? "jacob-1.17-x64.dll" :"jacob-1.17-x86.dll";
        try{
            /**
             * Reading jacob.dll file
             */
            InputStream inputStream = certificatemain.class.getResourceAsStream(libFile);
            /**
             *  Step 1: Create temporary file under <%user.home%>\AppData\Local\Temp\jacob.dll 
             *  Step 2: Write contents of `inputStream` to that temporary file.
             */
            File temporaryDll = File.createTempFile("jacob", ".dll");
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(temporaryDll);
            byte[] array = new byte[8192];
            for (int i = inputStream.read(array); i != -1; i = inputStream.read(array)){
                outputStream.write(array, 0, i);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            /* Temporary file will be removed after terminating-closing-ending the application-program */
            System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, temporaryDll.getAbsolutePath());
            LibraryLoader.loadJacobLibrary();

            ActiveXComponent comp=new ActiveXComponent("Com.Calculation");        
            System.out.println("The Library been loaded, and an activeX component been created");

            int arg1=100;
            int arg2=50;
            //using the functions from the library:        
            int summation=Dispatch.call(comp, "sum",arg1,arg2).toInt();
            System.out.println("Summation= "+ summation);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Now let me tell you how to register your DLL. I also followed same article you mentioned but not working when you are dealing with applet.

Go to `x86` framework using command line.

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`

to register do same as

`regasm.exe path_to_your_dll.dll /codebase`

Don't pass any other flag except `/codebase`. You are done with it... Still you find any problem let me know...