# How to use an OCX file in Jcob

Tags: java, ocx

I tried creating an ActiveXComponent object by clsid Like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, "C:\\Users\\TelC\\Downloads\\jacob-1.19\\jacob-1.19-x64.dll");
    LibraryLoader.loadJacobLibrary();
    ActiveXComponent comp=new ActiveXComponent("clsid:5B769435-52C8-11D2-B347-444553540000");
    System.out.println("The Library been loaded, and an activeX component been created");
}
```

but I get following exception:

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't find moniker
```

I would be happy if someone could explain me what I'm doing wrong.

I have not done anything out of my program , such as registering any dll(s) or something.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147193/cant-co-create-object-cant-find-moniker-jacob You should register the DLL I think.

Comment: @Freeman I don't know anything about installing JCO, I just added a jar file for jcob to my project. How should I install JCO?

Comment: @Freeman I mean jcob not jco, what is the difference between them and what is JCO good for?

Comment: JACOB is a JAVA-COM Bridge that allows you to call COM Automation components from Java. It uses JNI to make native calls to the COM libraries.<br />
SAP JCo is a communication library, based on RFC which is an SAP interface protocol that simplifies the programming of communication processes between systems.

Comment: @Freeman SAP is not free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new `ActiveXComponent` you should create it by the `createNewInstance` method:

```
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, "C:\\Users\\TelC\\Downloads\\jacob-1.19\\jacob-1.19-x64.dll");
    LibraryLoader.loadJacobLibrary();
    ActiveXComponent comp=ActiveXComponent.createNewInstance("clsid:5B769435-52C8-11D2-B347-444553540000");
    System.out.println("The Library been loaded, and an activeX component been created");
```

Comment: Yesss!! You saved my day. Thanks for your response.